# Unable to install VSTO, getting error that a compatible version of the .NET Framework is not installed

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I recently upgraded by Excel add-in project from .NET Framework 4 Client Profile to .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Now, I tried installing it in a Win 7 machine with .Net 4.5.2 installed, but I'm getting the error "The following Microsoft Office solution cannot be loaded because a compatible version of the .NET Framework is not installed".

Why am I getting this error while I have .NET Framework 4.5.2 installed in the machine?

Please advise.

EDIT: FYI, It seems to work fine on Win 8 machines.

Comment: Try to install [VSTO Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54251) on the end machine. Also check this post, especially the section named [Installing the Runtime by Using the Runtime Redistributable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712596(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: @PetLahev I had to upgrade to the latest VSTO Runtime to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to MS document. It says Office extension for .Net Framework 4 or later is not installed automatically except windows update.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/visual-studio-tools-for-office-runtime-installation-scenarios?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019

> The Office extensions for the .NET Framework 4 or later are not
> installed with Office, even if the .NET Framework 4 or later is
> already present when you install Office.
>
> The Office extensions for the .NET Framework 4 are installed with
> Office. End users can obtain the Office extensions for the .NET
> Framework 4.5 by installing a Windows update.

You will need to take one of above. If you want to install manually then click download link in MS site.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54251

This was my case.